# What happens to my DAO tokens after the 2016-June Attack?

Tags: the-dao, dao

Are my DAO tokens lost after the 2016-June attack? I understand they might hard fork to return the ether to everyone, but it seems like that would take some time to implement. What if the hard fork does not happen and more people take advantage of this loophole as time passes by?

Answer (score 1):

1. If the hard fork happens the ETH will be returned
2. If the hard fork does not happen and the attack continues then upon liquidation of the DAO, ETH refunds will be made proportional to your stake in the DAO.

Ethereum miners will have to decide which course of action to take and vote with their hash rate.

Comment: Links to this official plan?

Comment: @duckx I think "official" is the wrong word because Ethereum is not a corporation nor does it have a CEO. Miners will decide which forking plan if any passes. Having said that I think the words of Vitalik Buterin are watched the most closely and given the most weight: https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/06/17/critical-update-re-dao-vulnerability/